# XML file is loaded properly in Netbeans IDE but not in JAR that contains it

Tags: java, xml, netbeans, jar

I'm writing a game using [Tiled](http://mapeditor.org)'s TMX format for 2D tile mapping (said format being XML-based). When I build and run the program within the NetBeans IDE, it works flawlessly. However, the JAR file does not, kicking out the following error message:

```
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

Naturally this is followed by many NullPointerExceptions after the program continues running and attempts to reference the unloaded map.

Use of jar xvf has verified that the file is being built into the JAR correctly, and no extra data is being introduced - the unarchived copy is byte-for-byte identical to the one in my src/assets folder.

The relevant code follows; from GameScreenMain.java:

```
try {
    TMXMapReader mapReader = new TMXMapReader();
    map = mapReader.readMap(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test_map.tmx"));
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

From TMXMapReader.java:

```
public Map readMap(InputStream in) throws Exception {
    xmlPath = makeUrl(".");

    Map unmarshalledMap = unmarshal(in);

    //unmarshalledMap.setFilename(xmlFile)
    //
    return unmarshalledMap;
}

private Map unmarshal(InputStream in) throws Exception {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    Document doc;
    try {
        factory.setIgnoringComments(true);
        factory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
        factory.setExpandEntityReferences(false);
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        builder.setEntityResolver(entityResolver);
        InputSource insrc = new InputSource(in);
        insrc.setSystemId(xmlPath);
        insrc.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        doc = builder.parse(insrc);
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        throw new Exception("Error while parsing map file: " +
                e.toString());
    }

    buildMap(doc);

    return map;
}
```

From test_map.tmx:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map version="1.0" orientation="orthogonal" width="18" height="10" tilewidth="64" tileheight="64">
    <tileset firstgid="1" name="Indev" tilewidth="64" tileheight="64">
        <image source="graphics/Indev.png" trans="ff00ff" width="128" height="64"/>
        <tile id="1">
            <properties>
                <property name="collision" value="solid"/>
            </properties>
        </tile>
    </tileset>
    <layer name="Tile Layer 1" width="18" height="10">
        <data encoding="base64" compression="zlib">   eJxjYmBgYKISZiQRU8scXGZhEyfHLEYseok1k5A5uPTgM4sYc/C5DZccPj8yYVGHzRxi0wm10hw6BgB7xwES</data>
    </layer>
</map>
```

Why does the exact same file work in the IDE but not in the JAR?

Comment: My bet would be an incorrect location when constructing the `InputStream` but you don't show that code.

Comment: The InputStream is created in the first code block, as part of calling readMap(). (Sloppy, I know.)

Comment: Oh, sorry, my eyes get old and grey. Why don't you use `getResourceAsStream('/assets/test_map.tmx')`, assuming your build process retains that folder.

Comment: Okay, I tried changing the String a couple ways. The IDE starts kicking out the same error if I prepend the forward slash (or use '/test_map.tmx'), but not if I use 'assets/test_map.tmx'. The project classpath has src/assets included. I haven't customized the build script.

Comment: Print out what is loading before you try to parse it to verify that you're not loading different things in different cases.

Comment: I've now done so, and compared the results using textdiff.com, which reports that they're equal (and an eyeball check agrees). I've added the XML to the question.

Comment: Subtle change: using 'assets/test_map.tmx', the JAR no longer kicks out the prolog error, and I can verify that the file is being read. I have no idea why. At any rate, I can mark this answered if one of you wants to submit the above as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the resource resides in a an `assets` folder within the classpath, then you need to add this to the resource identifier (i.e. filename & path), e.g. `assets/test_map.tmx`.

It may work in the IDE because the current working directory is different then than when the program is running from the JAR. When run from the JAR it is impossible to have a working directory *within* the JAR as it is only a file. When run from the IDE the JAR is not constructed yet, every single resource exists as a file in the file system, a working directory e.g. at the `classes` folder is possible. Thus it is possible to have different behaviour when running from IDE or from JAR and relying on specific or implicit environment like the working directory.